# Named Routes Conflict Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controllers

I am creating a `Multilingual Laravel 5.2` application and I am trying to figure out how to **change language** when I already have the content.

**routes.php**

```
...
Route::get('home', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'SiteController@home'
]);
Route::get([
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'SiteController@inicio'
]);
...
```

I have `SiteController@home` and `SiteController@inicio`. So I change `session('language')` in `SiteController@change_language` like:

```
...
public function change_language ($lang){
    session(['language' => $lang]);
    return redirect()->action(SAME NAMED ROUTE, DIFFERENT LANGUAGE);
}
...
```

So, When I click on a button with

```
<a href="change_language/en">English</a>
```

from `/inicio` (`SiteController@inicio`) I should be redirected to the same named route (`SiteController@home`) so I can check the language and display appropriate content.

Any ideas of how to get the named route or something helpful?

Thank you :)

Comment: I have found this package [TranslatableRoutes](https://github.com/doitonlinemedia/TranslatableRoutes), a few days ago. Perhaps it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Fiete, this could work but for now I am trying to figure out how to get the named routes so I can reference them further. Thanks, I will keep it in mind.